# How to apply css on image imported by CSS

Tags: jquery, css

How can we apply CSS on the image which is imported by css through background: url('..') property .
eg: I want to apply border-radius on the image.jpg .

```
<div></div>

div {
  background: url('image.jpg'); 
}
```

Comment: you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/bkhdcLsL/

Comment: can we do this without styling div. for eg: i want my div to be square and image to be circle

Comment: you an use outline http://jsfiddle.net/bkhdcLsL/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly style background images. You can style the element the image is a background on; in this example, the `div`. If you want a border radius, just add it in CSS with `border-radius`.

Even if you have a border-radius set on the `div`, it will still have a square bounding box:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/');
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Text in here is not automatically inside the "circle."
</div>
```

Comment: can we do this without styling div. for eg: i want my div to be square and image to be circle

Comment: @ChimedPalden check my edit -- border-radius doesn't restrict the actual contents of the div.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve border radius, you have to provide the border radius attribute to the container object. here your object is div.

add like this :

```
div {
background: url('image.jpg'); 
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```